# In golang how to get an instance of interface by name in config file

Tags: spring, go

I want to know how can I inject dependency flexibly in golang just like java spring, Which is if I want to change a instance of an interface all I have to do is just to change some config file.

First I want to find some function like **getTypeByName()**, so I can just give a struct name like "mypkg.structName" in config file and load that struct by the function, but it seems that there is no such function in golang.

And now the most doable way i can think is to create a loader model to generate a [struct register file](https://play.golang.org/p/igmssSD9k2) to load all custom struct.

But I want to know is there have a easier way to do that, all is there some golang-style way to implement this flexibility?

Comment: There's facebook's [dependency injection lib](https://github.com/facebookgo/inject), but I'm still not very keen on dep injection to be honest, since it's prone to runtime (nil pointer type of) errors, where I'd prefer compile time errors.

Comment: Runtime-configured dependency injection seems very un-Go-like to me, it completely abandons the compile-time safety and intentional simplicity that are foundational to Go.

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is correct, since you can not instantiate a type if it's not defined during compilation. Otherwise, you need to use [`plugin`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/).

I'm not sure whether it's *easier* or not, but if you want the custom structs being organized in different packages, you can use similar approach as `database/sql`.

1. Define a factory package which consists of `Factory` interface and manage known factories. This package should export `Register` function for registering custom factory, and `New` function for creating instance of a given type. For example:

   ```
   package factory

   import (
       "strings"
       "sync"
   )

   type Factory interface {
       New(name string) (interface{}, bool)
   }

   var (
       mu        sync.RWMutex
       factories = make(map[string]Factory)
   )

   func Register(pkgName string, f Factory) {
       mu.Lock()
       defer mu.Unlock()

       if f == nil {
           panic("Factory is nil")
       }
       if _, exist := factories[pkgName]; exist {
           panic("Factory already registered")
       }

       factories[pkgName] = f
   }

   func New(typeName string) (interface{}, bool) {
       items := strings.Split(typeName, ".")
       if len(items) >= 2 {
           mu.RLock()
           defer mu.RUnlock()
           if f, exist := factories[items[0]]; exist {
               return f.New(items[1])
           }
       }
       return nil, false
   }
   ```
2. Create package which consists of your custom struct and implementing the `Factory` interface. Register the factory during initalization i.e. in `init()` function, e.g

   ```
   package pkga

   import "path/to/your/factory"

   type thisFactory struct {
   }

   type Alpha struct{}
   type Beta struct{}
   type Gamma struct{}

   func (f *thisFactory) New(name string) (interface{}, bool) {
       switch name {
       case "Alpha":
           return &Alpha{}, true
       case "Beta":
           return &Beta{}, true
       case "Gamma":
           return &Gamma{}, true
       }
       return nil, false
   }

   func init() {
       factory.Register("pkga", &thisFactory{})
   }
   ```
3. Repeat step (2) as you need.
4. Finally, in your main package, you can create an instance as follows:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"

       "path/to/your/factory"
       _ "path/to/custom/pkga"
       _ "path/to/custom/pkgb"
       //add more packages ...
   )

   func main() {
       a, _ := factory.New("pkga.Alpha")
       b, _ := factory.New("pkgb.Beta")
       c, _ := factory.New("pkga.Gamma")

       fmt.Printf("%T %T %T\n", a, b, c)
   }
   ```

Update: a working example is available [here](https://github.com/ipsusila/so/tree/master/inject).